# Reading from an Excel File and manipulating Data

Tags: excel, matlab, vector, conditional-statements

I'm using Matlab to read from an Excel file.  I'm supposed to be reading a column of integers called Change Due.  After I read the column I am supposed to be calculating the change,in Quarters,Dimes..etc

I can read the column no problem,and I understand the math of how to calculate the change. **however** using a condition to check the amount of change is difficult...

**Problem:**

I know that for Multiplication/Division of Vectors you can add a period to make it a scalar  **.*** or **./**

**But how do I parse through a vector with a condition?**

```
if(Change.<25&&Change.>=10)
```

I get this Error:

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
```

If I was to just simple leave the period out I would not get an error message but it only goes through the first row for calculations.

**Code:**

```
% Filename: Program_04_1
% Author: Stewart Moon
% Assisted by: No one
% Program Description:
% The purpose of this program is to demonstrate how to read from an Excel
% file and to then calculate the amount of coins it will take per row

clc % clc clears the contents of the command window
clear   % clear, clears all defined variables form the Matlab workspace
close all % closes all figure windows

% Declare Variables
Quarters=0;
Dimes=0;
Nickels=0;
Pennies=0;
TotalCoins=0;

% Output of the title and author to the command window
fprintf('Output for Program_04_1 written by Stewart Moon.\n')
fprintf('\nOriginal Data read from Program_04_1_Data.xlsx\n')
fprintf('\nMinimum Number of Coins Needed to Make Change\n')

Change=xlsread('Tutorial_04_1_Data.xlsx','Coins','B4:B43'); % Reading the column in Excel and storing it the variable Change

% Output Header Format
fprintf('\nChangeDue(cents) Quarters Dimes Nickels Pennies Total Coins\n\n')

table=[Change];
disp([table])
```

**Command Window Output:**

```
Output for Program_04_1 written by Stewart Moon.

Original Data read from Program_04_1_Data.xlsx

Minimum Number of Coins Needed to Make Change

ChangeDue(cents) Quarters Dimes Nickels Pennies Total Coins

 1
 4
 5
 6
10
14
15
16
20
24
25
29
30
31
35
37
40
42
45
49
50
54
55
56
60
64
65
68
70
73
75
77
80
81
85
88
90
91
95
99
```

> > 

**Calculating Change Pseudo Code:**

```
while(Change>0)

    if (Change>=25)
       Change=Change-25;
       TotalCoins=TotalCoins+1;
       Quarters=Quarters+1;
        end
     if (Change<25&&Change>=10)
       Change=Change-10;
       TotalCoins=TotalCoins+1;
       Dimes=Dimes+1;
        end
     if (Change<10&&Change>=5)
       Change=Change-5;
       TotalCoins=TotalCoins+1;
       Nickels=Nickels+1;
        end
     if (Change<5&&Change>=1)
       Change=Change-1;
       TotalCoins=TotalCoins+1;
       Pennies=Pennies+1;
        end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you want to achieve something like:

```
for i = 1 : length(Change)
% your conditions using indices for the array
% example: 
% if(Change(i) > 25)
%   instructions
% end
end
```